# finding the word like in a sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string like this:

`i would like to go to office, and i would like to go to market`

My question is: how many times the word `like` occurs in the string?

Please write a query.

Comment: this sounds like an assigment for us. what have you think about ?

Comment: Have a look at the SubStr function: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj93082.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a place where you can ask questions about programming and related subjects; it is not, however, a "do my homework for me" site. Questions asked here must demonstrate an understanding of the problem, should include the code you've written, and should be asking questions similar to "why doesn't this work as I expect?". On the other hand, some people may answer your question for you with the idea that if they tell you how to do it you won't have learned anything, leading to you failing your course, so that you will never bother us again. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexp_count`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT('i like to go , and i would like market', 'like')
FROM   DUAL;
```

Comment: Never used this function before. Really good to know.

Comment: Yes, regular expressions are powerfull.

Answer (score 0):

The word "like" occurs twice in the string you posted.

The following is a query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM SOME_TABLE
  WHERE SOME_VALUE = SOME_OTHER_VALUE
```

Share and enjoy.